# How to read strings and double from text file into link list

Tags: c++, string, double, ifstream

I'm wondering how I would go about reading this input file and storing it:

```
Tulsa 
129.50
Santa Fe 
70.00
Phoenix
110.00
San Diego
88.50
Yakama
150.25
```

Here is my cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "q2.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream in( "q2input.txt", ios::in );

    string loc;
    double price;

    while(fin >> loc >> price)
    {
       cout << "location: " << loc<< endl;
       cout << "price: " << price << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it only reads the first two lines. I know the syntax for reading as if it was divided into columns, but not this way.

Comment: Quick hack is to put in a read of a junk char to get the end of line. `fin >> loc >> junk >> price >> junk`. Not sure if this will work with a two character end of line marker like `\r\n`

Comment: `operator>>` for `string`s will stop when it hits a whitespace char, either don't use whitespace in city names or switch to `getline`.

Answer (score 2):

Reading a string stops on the first whitespace. That is, reading `Stanta Fe` into a string stops after `Santa`. As `Fe` isn't a valid floating point value reading then fails.

There are, at least, two solutions to the problem:

1. Instead of reading a `std::string` using `operator>>()` you'd use `std::getline()` after skipping whitespace using `std::ws` (there are plenty duplicate questions about how to do that properly).
2. You'd use a stream which doesn't consider `' '` as whitespace by `imbue()`ing a suitable `std::ctype<char>` facet. That's a bit more interesting and unconventional solution to the problem.

Given that it is unlikely that a teacher would accept that solution without explanation, it seems OK to provide code for the second approach:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

struct ctype_table {
    std::ctype_base::mask table[std::ctype<char>::table_size];
    template <int N>
    ctype_table(char const (&spaces)[N]): table() {
        for (unsigned char c: spaces) {
            table[c] = std::ctype_base::space;
        }
    }
};
struct ctype
    : private ctype_table
    , std::ctype<char>
{
    template <int N>
    ctype(char const (&spaces)[N])
        : ctype_table(spaces)
        , std::ctype<char>(ctype_table::table)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("q2input.txt");
    in.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new ctype("\n\r")));
    std::string name;
    double      value;
    while (in >> name >> value) {
        std::cout << "name='" << name << "' value=" << value << "\n";
    }
}
```